# Firebase-authentication type email/password credentials sent over https?

Tags: android, https, firebase-authentication

I have integrated Firebase-authentication type email/password with my android application, using the Firebase tutorial. For the sign-in phase, I'm using "signInWithEmailAndPassword (String email, String password)" function. My question is if the credentials are sent over a secure channel (https) or are in any way encrypted before being sent to the Firebase-auth server. Reading the docs, I have not found any specification yet regarding the use of https, nor I have found any reading the function description.

This is my function for authentication

```java
private FirebaseAuth mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
private void signIn(String email, String password) {
        Log.d("Log in", "signIn:" + email);


        //showProgressDialog();

        // [START sign_in_with_email]
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d("Sign in success!", "signInWithEmail:success");
                            Intent main2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main_activity_2.class);
                            startActivity(main2);

                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w("Failure:", "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Authentication failed!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            //updateUI(null);
                        }


                    }
                });
        // [END sign_in_with_email]
    }
```

And the function call:

```java
final TextView email = findViewById(R.id.email); 
final TextView pass = findViewById(R.id.passwd); 
signIn(email.getText().toString(), pass.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request is sent over a secure channel (https). [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password) is the exact REST API used for email/password sign-in.

Comment: Thanks! I missed that one! Following the tutorial posted by Firebase, it is not clear what happens with the credentials being sent.